# Should I put the gmap geocode to calculate the lat/lng from an address in the view.py or in the model.py?

Tags: django, google-maps, python-3.6, django-1.11

My goal is to:

1. take an address submitted by a user using generic python forms
2. take the address data and calculate the lat/lng for the address
3. store the address data and the lat/lng data in the same row of a database

I've been told that the geocode should be calculated within the models.py.

How does django take data submitted from a form make a calculation then input the entire data set into a database?

I'm using django 1.11, Python 3.6 and gmaps api.

I can calculate the lat/lng in the views.py but was told to put all business login in the models.py and I don't know how to move the lat/lng code into the models.py.

Look forward to any suggestions.

code portion I'd like to put in models.py in order to produce lat and lng input into my models.Model class.  I tried using the following but can't get lat lng to be produced.

```
class OwnerLocationEntry(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    location_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    address_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    unit_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=US_STATES_TER)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, blank=True)



    #create lat lng geocode

    def get_geocode(self):

        g = geocoders.GoogleV3(api_key=api_key)
        inputaddress = "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (self.address_number, self.street_name, self.city, self.state, self.zip_code)
        location = g.geocode(inputaddress, timeout=10)
        lat= location.latitude
        lng = location.longitude

        return lat, lng


    lat = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    lng = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

Comment: Could you add some more context? Perhaps your view/form/models?

Comment: @Brobin Thanks for taking a look.  I added the code I've been trying to get to work in my model.  Everything is added to my postgres db except the lat lng.  Sorry for not adding it sooner.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend overriding the `save` method of you model in order to get the lat/lng when creating/editing.

```
class OwnerLocationEntry(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lat, self.lng = self.get_geocode()
        super(OwnerLocationEntry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_geocode(self):
        ...
        return lat, lng
```

Then you may either have a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) with a `FormView` or a [generic view such as `CreateView` or `UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) that will handle creating the form, validating it, and saving it, which in turn will call the save method up above.